# Derelict3: seg fault on glfwPollEvents

Tags: opengl, d, glfw

I'm trying to get a basic GLFW example running with Derelict3 on D2. I pulled this example from the D mailing list archives: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/byorhjqpppsgqiwfrigd@forum.dlang.org

Here's my code so far:

```
import std.stdio;

import derelict.opengl3.gl;
import derelict.glfw3.glfw3;

pragma(lib, "DerelictGL3");
pragma(lib, "DerelictGLFW3");
pragma(lib, "DerelictUtil");
pragma(lib, "dl");

const int width = 800;
const int height = 600;

void init() {
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2d(0,0);
        glVertex2d(0,height);
        glVertex2d(width,height);
        glVertex2d(height,0);
    glEnd();
}

extern (C) {
    void resizeWindow(GLFWwindow window, int w, int h) {
    }

    void refreshWindow(GLFWwindow window) {
        writeln("Refresh");
        display();
    }

    void mouseMove(GLFWwindow window, int x, int y) {
    }

    void mouseClick(GLFWwindow window, int button, int action) {
    }

    int windowClose(GLFWwindow window) {
        //running = false;
        return GL_TRUE;
    }

    void keyTrigger(GLFWwindow window, int key, int action) {
        if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
            //running = false;
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    DerelictGL.load();
    DerelictGLFW3.load();

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        writeln("glfwInit didn't work");
        return;
    }

    auto window = glfwCreateWindow(width,height,GLFW_WINDOWED,"Hello 
DerelictGLFW3",null);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    init();

    // register callbacks
    /*
    glfwSetWindowRefreshCallback(window, &refreshWindow);
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, &resizeWindow);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, &mouseMove);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, &mouseClick);
    glfwSetWindowCloseCallback(window, &windowClose);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, &keyTrigger);
    */

    bool opened = true;
    while(opened) {
        display();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        writeln("Before");
        glfwPollEvents();
        writeln("After");
    }
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

This currently compiles and runs as expected, but as soon as I uncomment all of the callback registrations, I get a segfault just before `glfwPollEvents()`.

I'm not sure what's going on here. I thought it could be a library conflict, but everything else seems to run well.

Building with:

```
dmd -I$HOME/sandbox/Derelict3/import -L-L$HOME/sandbox/Derelict3/lib -ofgame test.d
```

Platform: Linux x64 (Fedora 17)

`$HOME/sandbox/Derelict3` is a git clone of https://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3

Also, is there's an example of rendering a simple shape using Derelict3 and GLFW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me using the latest Derelict3 (commit b133eda) and GLFW3 (26abe0a) from https://github.com/elmindreda/glfw.git

I'd do these things (in this order):

1. Ensure your Derelict shared libraries are up to date (run `rdmd build.d` in the Derelict3/build directory).
2. Ensure your GLFW3 libs are up-to date (I assume you're building from source, so make sure to pull and rebuild if new commits come in).  Don't forget to `make install`.
3. If you still experience the problem, try using GDB to get a backtrace (I recommend compiling your test code with -g).

Not really so simple example (uses programmable pipeline): https://gist.github.com/4090381

Comment: Well, that definitely makes me feel better. I had a hunch that it could be a versioning thing.  Thanks! It's just hard to get started (no examples anywhere).

Comment: Added a link to an example in my answer.  It uses the programmable pipeline so it's spread over a couple of files, but that's probably where you should be moving anyways.

Comment: It was an outdated version of glfw. Thanks!